# BadTokenException at ArrayAdapter add

Tags: android, exception, android-arrayadapter

I do a lots of searching to find the answer but still don't know what I do wrong.
I just tried to use AutoCompleteTextView with a dynamic arrayadapter.
But it don't work for me: (

My OnCreate method looks like:

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.travel_dest,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.statepanel));
pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 350, 500, true);
List<CharSequence> lastTravels = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
lastTravels.add("ITT");     
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lastTravels);
textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);       
textView.addTextChangedListener(this);
textView.setThreshold(1);
```

And my afterTextChanged implementation:

adapter.add ("HELLO");

And I get my Exception when calling the "add" method:

```
> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRoot$W@2b074218 is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:546)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:911)
at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:823)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1210)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1022)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$1700(AutoCompleteTextView.java:92)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$PopupDataSetObserver$1.run(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1670)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Just tried that if I call adapter.add in oncreate method I got the same exception

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.travel_dest,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.statepanel));
pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 350, 500, true);
List<String> lastTravels = new ArrayList<String>();
lastTravels.add("ITT");     
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lastTravels);
adapter.add("OTT");
textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);       
textView.addTextChangedListener(this);
textView.setThreshold(1);
textView.showDropDown();
```

Comment: It is not possible to add a autocomplettextview in a popupwindow.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that you are passing view as a context. Try to change `new PopupWindow(layout, 350, 500, true)` to `new PopupWindow(this, 350, 500, true)` (if `this` will be your activity.

Comment: Tried some variations but still dont work.. When the dropdown of the autocomplete should display it crash :s